# Glass menu based on data from a REST response.

Tags: android, rest, google-glass

I am working on an immersive GDK application (on XE16 current) that needs to present the user a menu based on results from a call to a REST server.

As in...glass calls `HTTP GET [Server]/user_token/friends` and gets back an ArrayList of Friend objects (which we have implemented and works).

Is there a good, simple way to take these objects and present the user a list of names accessible by voice or touch?

All of the examples I've seen use hard-coded menus and `inflater.inflate(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was showing a static menu, and asking the user (via voice recognition) for further information what he's looking for exactly if he clicks an item in the menu. So for example, you'd show "Friends" in the menu, if the user selects it, you open the voice recognition dialog and ask "Which friend do you want to poke?". You'll get his answer in return and can then iterate over the list of friends from your server. (make sure to do this in a background thread and show a "Loading"-dialog in the mean time)

Some sample code from my project: https://gist.github.com/TomTasche/20ff4802c1002c381f6f

This doesn't work if actually *displaying* the list is a requirement for you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if you have a List to iterate on:

```
        for (String itemTitle : itemTitles) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + offset++, Menu.FIRST, itemTitle);
    }
```

That goes inside of:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

And replaces:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.basketballscore, menu);
```

In my particular app which uses Low Frequency live cards in XE16, my service sends a comma delimited list of items to the MenuActivity as an extra.  I turn that string into the List to loop through.

Let me know if you need more code.